# Run Jar related .Java from cmd

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface, command, command-prompt

I am trying to do "javac Classname.java" from cmd prompt, and this Classname.java requires Jfreechart libraries/jars, and runs fine if compiled from Eclipse (because project package has jars imported).

But I want to run the file from cmd prompt and its not able to show me the output. It comes with errors like: ("package doesn't exist"), how to fix it? I need the class file and also run JNI commands to create header file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [set the classpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

You can do this in 2 ways.  Either use the `-classpath` or `-cp` option:

```
javac -cp jar1.jar;path/to/jar2.jar Classname.java
```

Or, if you need it to persist, use the `CLASSPATH` environmental variable:

```
set CLASSPATH=path1;path2
javac Classname.java
```

Comment: Right, but the -classpath option is the preferrable way.

Comment: @asgs, not really. Some apps have a classpath that is too big to fit in a command line, so they have to use environment variables. e.g. app servers.

Comment: @Paul Grime: "-cp" *is* the way to go.  In most modern versions of windows, it shouldn't be any problem to make it as long as you want and put it in a .cmd file.

Comment: @Paul Grime Classpath being too big is never a problem, like paulsm4 said. The actual problem is setting the $classpath environment variable when you intend to run more than one application each of which requiring a different set of libraries, which might result in a clash. Also note -classpath is the more consistenly supported option than just -cp.

Answer (score 3):

If you have already managed to run your code in Eclipse, then Eclipse can help you.

In the "Debug" view, you should have something like this remaining after you have run your code:

[image: Screenshot of Debug view]

If you right-click the bottom "terminated" text and select "Properties", you will get something like this:

[image]

You can copy the command line content and use that to run your app from the command line, or use it to set the classpath as the other answers have advised.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the directory paths and/or .jar libraries to your "-classpath" command-line argument.

Depending on how many libraries you've got, you might well wind up with a .sh script (Linux) or .cmd file (windows) that looks something like this:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=230258

```
java -cp jts.jar:jcommon-1.0.0.jar:jfreechart-1.0.0.jar:jhall.jar:other.jar:rss.jar -Xmx256M jclient.LoginFrame .
```

If you're on Windows, you'd use ";" as a separator (instead of *nix ":").

'Hope that helps!